# Why has this answer promoting a product been deleted?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, low-quality-posts, specific-audit

Why has this been removed?  It's a valid answer and the links are valid too.  He may be promoting a product, but the answer is still valid.

[Low Quality Answer Test](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32263352)

Comment: Can't see the deleted post in the audit, but could be possibly removed due to spam.

Comment: It was a spam removal. Though 4/5 people have failed this review audit so far...

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about why this review item was an audit, and why you failed it, or are you asking why the answer was deleted in the first place?

Comment: Why was it deleted: because the user posted 10 mostly very duplicative answers that all linked it, 9 of which were within an hour and a half, and nothing else.  Why was it an audit: because it was deleted by a spam flag rather than a rude/abusive flag.  It's not a good audit.  I've removed it from the audit pool.  All three of the audits you failed were of similarly low quality, so I've lifted your review suspension.

Comment: @HenryEcker - I am not questioning Makyens action.  But, In isolation it is not spam.  So, perhaps it should not be used as a test question :-)

Comment: @Ryan hopefully you also banned the system from doing reviews :-)

Comment: "This page provides examples, *as well as free conversion trials:*" That's, like, a big red warning flag that it's the kind of promotion that is not okay. That the answer doesn't do other not-okay things doesn't change that.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Well, as you can see, this is fine now and Mods will lift your review ban when you say this promotional text is fine and very acceptable.

Comment: @Tom audits are supposed to be clear. This one has hints that it *might* be spam, but even then it's not *totally* clear: they can't see the other 8 answers the user posted that day, because we deleted them (though in this case if you looked you'd see the user has *no* answers, which would give away that it's an audit).  Sometimes people recommend commercial software and it's not spam.  Also, the low-quality answers queue is mostly looking for non-answers.  There isn't even an option to complete a review there by flagging it (which is not great, really).

Comment: @RyanM I would agree with you when "edit" would also fail that audit (I'm not sure right now). If it would not, then I disagree. That promotional text is not "looks ok".

Answer (score 28):

I deleted it as spam, because it's intentionally deceptive spam. The user posted 9 answers in 1 hour 16 minutes, all with undisclosed affiliation linking to the same site. All 9 answers were very similar, with most of them identical to each other. In every answer, the user intentionally attempts to deceive readers by recommending the library as "I am using it too", or something very similar, when, in fact, the user is affiliated in an ownership role, as they indicate in [their only other answer, which is from a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68222220).